# Passing component in post API header

Tags: reactjs

i'm new in reactjs. i'm getting a value from a post APi call and using it as body of other post API, but when i pass it in body, it didn't show expected result. i have 2 files

```js
// DeviceList.Js
render() {
  const  { deviceId }  = this.state;

      return (
        
          deviceId 
        
      )
    }
}

export default DeviceList ;
```

```js
// Count.js
const today = new Date();
  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ auth 
       },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "device_id": <DeviceList />,
        "day":    today.getDate(),
        "month":  today.getMonth()+ 1,
        "year":   today.getFullYear()
    })
  };
  fetch('url'/api/Count', requestOptions)
      .then(response =>  response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ countId: data.result.count }))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: First, try to make a function within a component that does the intended work for you. Then learn how you can work with async functions and fetch. read here https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/

Comment: i have made a function in component but got can't get exported can you give me an example please??